# How to return results from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables for a quiz application:

```
[Questions]
_id, question, correctAnswerId

[Answers]
_id, answer, questionId
```

When I query for a question, e.g.

```
SELECT question FROM Questions WHERE _id = 2
```

I also want to get the (correct and incorrect) answers associated with that question. How can I query for a question and answers all at once so I don't have to query for answers separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT q.question, a.answer
FROM Questions q JOIN Answers a ON q._id = a.questionId
WHERE q._id = 2
```